# Find a basis for the topology and find the interior given a subset

Tags: general-topology

Consider $\mathbb{Z}$ with the topology $\tau_{0}=\{A \subseteq \mathbb{Z}: 0\in A\} \cup \{\emptyset \}$ and $5\mathbb{Z}\subseteq \mathbb{Z}$. First of all I want find a basis for $\tau_{5\mathbb{Z}}=\{U \cup V: U\in \tau_{0} \hspace{0.1cm} \text{and} \hspace{0.1cm} V\subseteq 5\mathbb{Z} \}$.

Try to express the following $\tau_{5\mathbb{Z}}=\{U \cup V: 0\in U \subseteq \mathbb{Z} \hspace{0.1cm} \text{and} \hspace{0.1cm} V\subseteq 5\mathbb{Z} \}$.

I want to find $\mathcal{B}\subseteq \tau_{5\mathbb{Z}}$ s.t. for all $U_{1}\in \tau_{5\mathbb{Z}}$ there exists $\mathcal{B}'\subseteq \mathcal{B}$ s.t. $U_{1}=\bigcup \mathcal{B}'$, I think a candidate could be $\mathcal{B}=5\mathbb{Z} \cup \{\emptyset\}$ (If true, how would it be a quick test that it is indeed a base?)

Secondly, for $B=\{10x: x\in \mathbb{Z} y -10 \leq x \leq 10\}$, i want to find $int(B)$, $\overline{B}$, $B'$ y $\partial(B)$.

Considering the definition of interior point and closure point, I believe that $int(B)=B$ either $\overline{B}=B$.

any suggestions for the derivative set and the border?, in general, any contribution to this? any help is welcome

Comment: Your candidate for $\mathcal{B}$ doesn't work. The set $\{ 0, 1 \}$ for example is open in $(\mathbb{Z}, \tau_{5 \mathbb{Z}})$, but there is no basis element containing $1$ that is contained in the set.

Comment: Also, if you are trying to find a basis for $\tau_{5\mathbb Z}$, then you probably want it sto satisfy some additional criterion, otherwise you could just use $\tau_{5\mathbb Z}$ itself, as every topology is a basis for itself.

Comment: Ok my initial comments were kind of a disaster, have deleted two of them though I have left one relevant one up.  To correct my other comment, $5\mathbb Z\cup\{\emptyset\}$ is a union between $5\mathbb Z$, a subset of integers, and$ \{\emptyset\}$, a subset of the power set $\mathcal P(\mathbb Z)$, so I'm not sure how that's supposed to define a topology, unless I'm still misreading.

Comment: Agreed, I am also not exactly sure what is meant by that, since a basis is supposed to be a subset of $\mathcal{P} (\mathbb{Z})$. I interpreted it to mean $\{ \{ x \} | x \in 5 \mathbb{Z} \} \cup \{ \emptyset \}$; i.e., singletons containing multiples of $5$, but there is definitely something strange with the notation.

Comment: Somehow I missed this earlier - $\tau_0$ is not a topology at all as far as I can tell - it does not include the empty set.  And similarly neither is $\tau_{5\mathbb Z}$.  I think OP might wish to review the problem he is working on and make sure he is transcribing it correctly.

Comment: $5 \mathbb{Z} \subset \mathbb{Z}$ is a bit redundant. Is that what you meant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @M J mentioned in the comments, there are some notational issues in this question; for example, to ensure that $\tau_0$ is a topology, it should *really* be defined as $\tau_0 = \{ U \subseteq \mathbb{Z} | 0 \in U \} \cup \{ \emptyset \}$. Obviously it is not true that $0 \in \emptyset$, so it is necessary to explicitly include $\emptyset$ in this definition.

Also provided in the comments is the fact that since every topology is trivially a basis for itself, you can just take $\mathcal{B} = \tau_{5 \mathbb{Z}}$.

Let $\mathcal{C}$ denote the power set of $5 \mathbb{Z}$, along with $\mathbb{Z}$ itself. We claim that the collection $\tau_{5 \mathbb{Z}} = \tau_0 \cup \mathcal{C}$. This is simple to check. Let $B \in \tau_{5 \mathbb{Z}}$. If $0 \in B$, then $B \in \tau_0$ by definition. On the other hand, if $0 \notin B$, then we conclude $B = V \subseteq 5 \mathbb{Z} \implies B \in \mathcal{C}$. For the reverse inclusion, take two cases and use the definition for $\tau_{5 \mathbb{Z}}$. If $B \in \tau_0$, then we can take $V = \emptyset \subseteq 5 \mathbb{Z}$, so that $B \cup V = B \in \tau_{5 \mathbb{Z}}$. If $B \in \mathcal{C} - \{ \mathbb{Z} \}$ ($B = \mathbb{Z}$ was already covered in the case where $B \in \tau_0$), then $B \subseteq 5 \mathbb{Z}$ and we can take $U = \emptyset \in \tau_0$ so that $U \cup B = B \in \tau_{5 \mathbb{Z}}$.

(By the way, $\mathcal{C}$ constitutes a topology on $\mathbb{Z}$ that is not comparable to $\tau_0$; also, $\tau_{5 \mathbb{Z}}$ is strictly finer than both $\tau_0$ and $\mathcal{C}$. Besides $\mathcal{B} = \tau_{5 \mathbb{Z}}$, other bases for this topology include

$$\mathcal{B}' = \{ \{ 0, k \} | k \in \mathbb{Z} \} \cup (\{ \{ x \} | x \in 5 \mathbb{Z} \} \cup \{ \mathbb{Z} \})$$

and

$$\mathcal{B}'' = \{ \{ 0, k \} | k \in \mathbb{Z} \} \cup \{ \{ x \} | x \in 5 \mathbb{Z} \}$$

These facts I leave for you to check.)

Now considering the set $A = \{ 10 x | -10 \le x \le 10, x \in \mathbb{Z} \}$, we can actually enumerate it: $A = \{ -100, -90, ..., -10, 0, 10, ..., 90, 100 \}$. Since $0 \in A$, then by what we just showed, $A \in \tau_0 \subseteq \tau_{5 \mathbb{Z}}$. That is to say, $A$ is open.

Since $A$ is open, we have immediately that its interior ${\rm Int} A = \boxed{A}$.

Recall that ${\rm Cl} A$ is the smallest closed set containing $A$. Consider the set $D = \boxed{A \cup(\mathbb{Z} - 5 \mathbb{Z})}$ (where "$-$" denotes the set-theoretic difference); we claim that ${\rm Cl} A = D$. It is easy to show that $D$ is closed, for its complement $\mathbb{Z} - D$ is a subset of $5 \mathbb{Z}$; thus, $\mathbb{Z} - D \in \mathcal{C} \subseteq \tau_{5 \mathbb{Z}}$. To see that $D$ is the *smallest* closed set containing $A$, note that for any strictly smaller subset $E \subset D$ that contains $A$, the complement $\mathbb{Z} - E$ (1) does not contain $0$, and (2) contains some element of $\mathbb{Z} - 5 \mathbb{Z}$. Therefore, $\mathbb{Z} - E$ is not an element of either $\tau_0$ or $\mathcal{C}$ and thus cannot be open.

For the set of limit (a.k.a. accumulation) points of $A$, we claim that $A' = \boxed{\mathbb{Z} - 5 \mathbb{Z}}$. For any $x \in 5 \mathbb{Z}$, the singleton $\{ x \}$ is open (since it is a element of $\mathcal{C} \subseteq \tau_{5 \mathbb{Z}}$) and either does not intersect $A$ or intersects $A$ only at the point $x$ itself. For any $x \notin 5 \mathbb{Z}$, let $U$ be an open set containing $x$. If $U \in \tau_0$, then $0 \in U$, so that $U$ intersects $A$ at $0 \ne x$. On the other hand, if $U \in \mathcal{C}$, then the only possibility is that $U = \mathbb{Z}$, which, again, intersects $A$ at $0 \ne x$.

The boundary of $A$ is simply ${\rm Bd} A = {\rm Cl} A - {\rm Int} A$, which in this case is also equal to $\boxed{\mathbb{Z} - 5 \mathbb{Z}}$.

Comment: Your help is really useful

Comment: There is a doubt that I have been struggling with all this time, when you say  and either does not intersect $A$ or intersects $A$ only at the point $x$ itself, what do you mean, I really don't know how you show that the set of limit is $\mathbb{Z}-5\mathbb{Z}$, I try to see it with the definition that a point $x$ is bounded if for any open $U$ of a neighborhood comprising $x$ s.t. $U-\{x\} \cap A \neq \emptyset$ can you help me a little bit with it?

Comment: A *limit point* of $A$ is a point $x$ such that every neighborhood of $x$ intersects $A$ at a point other than $x$ itself. We don't worry about boundedness here.